How can i import a database using sqlpackage that has multiple parts?
I have a database named TempDB. I have split the database into a number of parts because it is quite large. I used 7-sip and have 10 parts. so for example tempDB1.bacpac tempdb2.bacpac etc.
Now if i import it I use the following
SqlPackage /a:Import /tsn:"{yourserver}.database.windows.net,1433" /tdn:"TempNewDB" 
/tu:"sqladmin" /tp:"{your_password}" /sf:"C:\TempDB1.bacpac"

and then
SqlPackage /a:Import /tsn:"{yourserver}.database.windows.net,1433" /tdn:"TempNewDB" 
/tu:"sqladmin" /tp:"{your_password}" /sf:"C:\TempDB2.bacpac"

SqlPackage /a:Import /tsn:"{yourserver}.database.windows.net,1433" /tdn:"TempNewDB" 
/tu:"sqladmin" /tp:"{your_password}" /sf:"C:\TempDB3.bacpac"

until i reach the last one.
will this restore the entire db ? and can i do it in some sort of loop ?
